# Determine the domain-sets of $f(z)=z\bar{z}/(z^2+\bar{z}^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, principal-ideal-domains

Determine the domain-sets of $$f(z)=\frac{z\bar{z}}{z^2+\bar{z}^2}$$

Here's my attempt:

Consider z = x+iy,

$z^2+\bar{z}^2 = (x+iy)^2 +(x-iy)^2 = 2x^2$

we know that $z^2+\bar{z}^2 \neq 0$ and so $x \neq 0$

> The solution is $\Bbb{C}$ \ {z = x + iy | x = y or x = -y}

I don't really understand the solution or the steps that will lead to it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You made an error: $(x+iy)^2 +(x-iy)^2 = 2x^2$ is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a slight error:$$\begin{align}z^2+\bar{z}^2=&(x+iy)^2+(x-iy)^2
\\=&(x^2+2ixy+i^2y^2)+(x^2-2ixy+i^2y^2)
\\=&2x^2+2i^2y^2
\\=&2(x^2-y^2)
\\2(x^2-y^2)\ne & 0
\\x^2\ne&y^2
\\x\ne&\pm y\end{align}$$
so the solution should be:
$$\mathbb{C}\backslash\{z=x+iy\,|\,x=\pm y\}$$
you could also word it as:
$$\left|\Re(z)\right|\ne\left|\Im(z)\right|$$

Comment: Oh yes ! thank you so much